# AWS S3 - How to wait until entire directory is accessible after uploading it?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In AWS docs there's this example:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-s3.html#uploading-a-file

It shows how can we wait until the object is accessible after uploading it.
Now I'd like to wait until entire directory accessible after uploading it with `uploadDirectory` method. I don't think it's a good idea to poll for each file in a directory as this would be a lot of requests and it would probably be slow.

Is there a way to put an entire manifest of files that should be accessible in a single poll request?

Comment: Is this really a problem?  Unless you are overwriting existing objects, anything you upload should be available immediately.  It wssn't always the case, but all S3 regions support read-after-write consistency on new objects.  Anything uploaded should not require a wait.

Comment: Sometimes after upload files were unavailable. They appeared later. So yes - it is (or at least it was) a problem.

Answer (score 1):

s3 does not maintain any directory and any meta-data around it.

There are only two level of partitions one at bucket level and other at object level that's why you cannot check any directory existence.

You can use parallel calls for all objects in  `<bucket>/<directory>` to check if they are accessible.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of would be to simply list existing objects in directory on specific bucket and check it with my local list of files (or at least check number of files).